# Magento 2 MFTF test : Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, magento2

We are running the Magento function testing framework in Magento Vannila 2.4.2 enterprise.
We used devious documentation for all setups.
https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html

while runing below command we are getting issue,
vendor/bin/codecept run functional -c dev/tests/acceptance/codeception.yml
vendor/bin/mftf run:test AdminLoginSuccessfulTest --remove

Could anyone can help on this.

Here is the Error

AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest: Admin login successful test
Test tests/functional/Magento/_generated/default/AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest.php:AdminLoginSuccessfulTest
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException] unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: Make sure that your chrome browser version and [chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) version must be the same.